# Only run @Test2 when @Test1 passes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

With TestTNG, how to only execute `@Test2` when `@Test1` passes?

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    @beforemethod
    public static beforemethod() {
        /////
    }

    @test
    public static void firsttest() {
        \\\\
    }

    @test
    public static void secondtest() {
        \\\\\\
    }

    @test
    public static void thirdtest() {
        \\\\
    }

    @Aftermethod
    public static aftermethod() {
        \\\
    }
```

When `firsttest()` passes then `secondtest()` should execute, otherwise it should stop the execution.

How can we write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dependsOnMethods` annotation like so:

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "method1" } )
```

Then your test will execute only if  method1 was successful (and always after it).

Comment: Thanks and ll let you know after trying this method @idos

Comment: You can safely remove curly brackets: @Test(dependsOnMethods="method1")

Comment: I like the curly braces (;

Comment: If you like it :+1: from me (-;

Comment: but do not do this.. tests should always be independent of each-other

Comment: I disagree. There are instances when tests are just dependant and that could be a valid design/outcome.

Comment: @Idos In which case you could combine the two tests into one. With proper assertion methods and error handling in place you could be killing two birds with one stone.